# Completion block for dismiss light box

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there way to execute the code right after lightBox has been dismissed? I am looking for an equivalent of completion block:

```
Navigator.dismissLightBox();
//wait for it to dismiss and execute code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback in [passProps](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=showlightboxparams-) and invoke that callback in `componentwillunmount`

```
Navigation.showLightBox({
  screen: "example.LightBoxScreen",
  passProps: {
    onDismiss: () => console.log('dismissed')
  }
});
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but if you have several buttons on the lightBox you'll have to track that too. It's not hard to implement but code seems kinda ugly. Also you're moving code from button's on tap prop to its parent (screen presented as a lightBox) onDismiss block which is not "react way" at all.

Comment: Why do you need to handle the dismiss in the buttons as well? the component you show in the lightBox gets unmounted either way.

Comment: Because I want to execute this completion block after it dismissed from tap handler of one of the buttons.

Comment: I guess we have no alternatives. I don't like this approach but that answers my question so I accept it.